# Mixed-effects models for within-subject psych experiment (in Stata)

Tags: stata, multilevel-analysis, psychology

I have a question about how to best analyze data from an experimental psychology study. Briefly, 250 participants were asked to assign four different pictures (Pictures A - D) to two different conditions (Conditions A - B). I would like to know whether Pictures A, B, and C were more likely to be assigned to Condition A relative to Picture D, after adjusting for relevant participant characteristics (e.g., demographic factors). The original plan was to fit a multilevel (random-intercepts) logistic model, in which participants were considered a random factor to account for the fact participants' picture assignments are likely correlated across the four pictures (i.e., within-subject picture assignment correlation). This is the general code I used in Stata (for the crude, unadjusted model).

```
xtmelogit condition_A pic_A pic_B pic_C || id:, variance OR
```

However, I have a few questions about the appropriateness of this method of analysis. First, by setting up the model in this way, does this essentially make the sample size within the level 2 groups four (i.e., the four pictures within each level 1, participant, group)? Also, I know that participant characteristics aren't really a random-sample of all possible characteristics, but they are characteristics of the level 2 groups, and thus I included these as level 2 covariates. Is this correct? Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks right, PotterFan. One thing that is unclear is how the experimental condition enters the model. Perhaps that is condition A or B and hence your interest in contrasting these two choices?

In terms of your level 2 sample size, that is 250 persons. Because each of the 250 persons has 4 data points your level 1 sample size is 250*4 = 1,000. You mention groups in your statement, and I am not sure what you mean by that.

Adding level 2 (person) predictors to the model will reduce the level 2 variance, thus helping you to explain between-person differences in choosing A over B. It is generally desirable to account for person characteristics if you believe those are at all related to choice or you want to explore whether choices vary as a function of person characteristics.